# How to tackle redirect to an external url in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, redirect, next.js, external

I have in place my `next.config.js` file with regular **redirect** rules, all within the same domain and all works fine. But in a specific case, I need to redirect the request from a certain URL (mydomain.com/abc) to a different domain. i.e differentdomain.com

How do I go about creating this rule to redirect to an external link in NextJs?

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: The [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) say to use `window.location` in those cases rather than `router.push`. If that doesn't help, you'll need to provide code for what you tried so we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: I've used the `nextjs-redirect` library with a set of custom redirects on my `next.config.js` file.

Comment: External redirect rules are built into next.config.js now (see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The latest version of Next.js has this built in using the `next.config.js` script (see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects). No need for additional plugins.

To test, copy the NextJs sample app:

```sh
npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/tree/master/learn-starter"
```

Add a `next.config.js` file to the root folder with the following code:

```js
// this simply tests the redirecting of the root path (source)
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: 'https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66662033',
        permanent: false,
        basePath: false
      },
    ]
  },
};
```

When you start the app `npm run dev` and visit localhost:3000, it should redirect to the destination URL specified in the next.config.js script (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66662033).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

You can try using window.location

Here's an example in which upon visiting a page it redirects the user to external url

```
// pages/redirect

import {useEffect} from 'react'
export default function redirect() {
    useEffect(() => {
        window.location.assign('https://duckduckgo.com/')
    })
    return(
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when you return the page, it returns to  page/redirect and redirects again to the location

Comment: …and the much bigger problem is that it works only with JavaScript enabled and will be ignored by search engines etc